# Keras-js input data error in Node-Red (not recognized as Float32Array)

Tags: javascript, node.js, machine-learning, keras, node-red

After exporting my keras model and weights, I tried the following code in node.js (v6.9.4), and it runs OK:

```
const KerasJS = require('keras-js');

const model_folder = '... model_files_folder';

const model_file_path = {
    model: model_folder + 'model.json',
    weights: model_folder + 'model_weights.buf',
    metadata: model_folder + 'model_metadata.json'
};

const model_config = {
    filepaths: model_file_path,
    gpu: false,
    filesystem: true
};

const model = new KerasJS.Model(model_config);

model.ready().then(() => {
    const inputData = {
        'input': new Float32Array(5)
    }
    console.log('Input: ' + inputData.input);
    return model.predict(inputData)
    }).then(outputData => {
        var out = outputData['output']
        console.log('Output: ' + out);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err)
    })
```

I got the result as:

```
> Input: 0,0,0,0,0
Output: 0.4446795582771301,0.0000053633639254258014,1.1930331722531662e-11,3.77190296774188e-8,1.060054266588395e-10
```

I changed the settings.js file of Node-Red to include Keras-js:

```
functionGlobalContext: {
    os:require('os'),
    KerasJS:require('keras-js')
    // ...
},
```

and this is the test function I wrote in Node-Red (v0.17.5):

```
const KerasJS = global.get('KerasJS');

(...model_folder,  model_config, etc.
 same as the above codes tested in Node.js...)

model.ready()
  .then(() => {
    const inputData = {
    'input': new Float32Array(5)
    }
    node.warn('Input: ' + inputData.input);
    return model.predict(inputData)
  })
  .then(outputData => {
    var out = outputData['output']
    node.warn('Output: ' + out);
    msg.payload = {
        'Output': out
    };
    node.send(msg);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    node.error(err);
  })

return null;
```

But I got the following error:

```
function : (error)
"Error: predict() must take an object where the values are the flattened data as Float32Array."
```

I got confused since I assigned the inputData.input as a Float32Array already. Could anybody help me to fix this? Thank you!